# How can I get data from DB in my service layer?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a method in my repository `getUserByNameAndAge()`, which returns a user from DB by 2 arguments. In my service layer I need to check, if I don't have in DB user with requested name, I need to throw some custom `InvalidUserNameException`, and if I don't have in db user with such age, I need to throw some custom `InvalidUserAgeException`. But I really can't understand how can I do this.

Here is my repository

```
interface UserRepository : JpaRepository<CountryLocalization?, Long?> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT u.name, u.age FROM users AS u" +
            " WHERE u.name = :name AND u.age = :age",
        nativeQuery = true)
    fun getUserByNameAndAge(
        @Param("name") name: String,
        @Param("age") age: Int
    ): User?
}
```

So how can I implement my service?

```
@Service
class UserServiceImpl (val userRepository: UserRepository) : UserService {
    override fun getUserByNameAndAge(name: String, age: Int): User {    
        /// implementation   
    }
}
```

Comment: First, you need to actually _use_ your repository to get data. Then you might need to change your approach: 1) get the user by id and throw that InvalidUserNameException if you don't get anything and 2) if you got a user check the age and throw the InvalidUserAgeException if it's wrong. With just one query you'll be able to check for the combination of name and age but you can't tell what was invalid if you don't get any results.

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't implement the repository interface, but inject it into your Service. You can do that with @Autowired annotation, and simply use that in your method. Something like this:

```
@Service
class UserServiceImpl : UserService {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var userRepository:UserRepository

    fun getUserByNameAndAge(name: String, age: Int): User =
        userRepository.getUserByNameAndAge(name, age)
}
```